# Distinguishing the Besov and Triebel-Lizorkin spaces

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, ap.analysis-of-pdes, harmonic-analysis

Theorem 2.3.9. in Triebel's [Theory of Function Spaces](https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-3-0346-0416-1) states that the Besov space $B^{s_1, p_1}_{q_1} (\mathbb R^d)$ coincides with the Triebel-Lizorkin space $F^{s_2, p_2}_{q_2} (\mathbb R^d)$ if and only if $s_1 = s_2$ and $p_1 = p_2 = q_1 = q_2$.

Suppose $$\| \cdot\|_{B^{s_1, p_1}_{q_1}} \sim \|\cdot \|_{F^{s_1, p_1}_{q_1}}$$

One can argue by dimensional analysis to show that the *regularity* exponents must coincide, $s_1 = s_2$, the *integrability* exponents must coincide, $p_1 = p_2$, and the *summability* exponents must coincide, $q_1 = q_2$. For example, to prove the latter, let us consider a superposition of functions localised at $n$ different dyadic frequencies, $u_n = \sum_{j = 1}^{n} e^{2\pi i x \cdot \xi_j} \chi$ for $|\xi_j| = 2^j$ and $\operatorname{supp}\widehat \chi \subseteq \{ |\xi| \ll 1\}$, we have
$$
\begin{align}
&\| u_n\|_{B^{0, p}_{q}}  \sim n^{1/q}\\
&\| u_n\|_{F^{0, p}_{q}}  \sim n^{1/q}
\end{align}$$
Triebel argues that we can use this to show $p = q$, however I find the claim a bit dubious. If someone can give a more detailed explanation or an alternative proof, that would be appreciated!

On a more abstract note, how should one think about the non-equivalence $B^{s, p}_{q} (\mathbb R^d) \neq F^{s, p}_{q} (\mathbb R^d)$ when $p \neq q$?
 It is clear how the two spaces are different technique-wise; studying the Besov scale is pretty easy, as in this case we're just summing up $L^p$-norms of Littlewood-Paley pieces, which allows us to apply Bernstein. The Triebel-Lizorkin scale on the other hand is much more difficult, since by summing pointwise first, we typically have to use vector-valued estimates, using maximal functions to perform averaging, or interpolating between sequence spaces (for example, see [[BrezisMironescu]](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/PL00001378) for a nice proof of Sobolev embedding). But otherwise the two norms seem to measure the same quantities. When can we expect, e.g. in energy estimates, the Besov scale to show up v.s. the Triebel-Lizorkin scale, and vice versa?

**EDIT:** I've found the answer to my first question, which in turn is somewhat of an answer to my second question. We modify our $u_n$, not only modulating $\chi$ but also translating, $u_n (x) := \sum_{j = 1}^n e^{2\pi i x \cdot \xi_j} \chi(x - 1000000^j)$. Translation doesn't change frequencies, and the $L^p$-norm and thus Besov norm is invariant.

$$||u_n||_{B^{0, p}_q} \sim n^{1/q}$$

However summing pointwise is clearly not invariant under different translations. Each $e^{2\pi i x \cdot \xi_j} \chi(x - 1000000^j)$ is a Schwartz function adapted to a ball centered at $x = 1000000^j$ so the masses are essentially disjoint, thus

$$||u_n||_{F^{0, p}_q} \sim n^{1/p}$$

Note that the summability exponent $q$, which is supposed to measure the number of frequency scales, has been supplanted by the integrability exponent $p$! This could also give a nice explanation for why there is a greater degree of flexibility in the choice of summability exponent for the Triebel-Lizorkin embedding theorems compared to the Besov embedding theorems, but I haven't thought this through completely...